# Bootstrap modal scrollbar gets stuck on iOS

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I am using bootstrap modal, in that, one html video and GIF image is there. When I scroll that modal on iOS its get stuck. I tried to solve issue by giving height and scroll to modal-body but it still get disable. Anyone suggest a idea to fix this issue?

Comment: If you're able to, can you give a link to the page? I'd like to check this out, but without looking at the page, I can't.

Comment: Thanks but I am not able share link because site have authentication. Site will not open at your end. Do you have any idea what is the reason, it's because of heavy video or gif image or anything else because I have tried lot but not able to figure out what is the issue.

Comment: a jsfiddle might help ..

Comment: I think its because of the limitations apple imposes on video playback on iOS. See this link: http://blog.millermedeiros.com/unsolved-html5-video-issues-on-ios/
If you can't post code, post a screenshot describing what exactly is wrong. Might be helpful

Comment: I have created a fiddle for the same. I have embedded mp4 video locally which is not coming in this. Please refer following link for my issue https://jsfiddle.net/2ksgfahm/

Comment: thanks for help. There was a issue in scrollbar plugin that I have used in modal.